# Dev Container networking incredibly slow to connect, but fine after that

Tags: docker, wsl-2, vscode-devcontainer

I have an API deployed onto AWS which I am trying to test from within a Dev Container. I noticed that responses are incredibly slow but the latency on AWS was reportedly very small, so I ran a timing test using curl:

```
curl -o /dev/null -XPOST -s -w 'Establish Connection: %{time_connect}s\nTTFB: %{time_starttransfer}s\nTotal: %{time_total}s\n' https://<my api>.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/urls/
```

When I run it from within a Dev Container running on Docker Desktop on WSL2, it takes 11 seconds just to establish a connection:

```
Establish Connection: 11.154874s
TTFB: 11.291783s
Total: 11.291815s
```

When I run it from WSL2, I see the whole request complete very quickly:

```
Establish Connection: 0.036608s
TTFB: 0.112057s
Total: 0.112094s
```

This is not the case for sites like `google.com`, which establish very quickly even in the Dev Container:

```
Establish Connection: 0.040978s
TTFB: 0.145377s
Total: 0.145745s
```

So I'm facing an issue where it looks like the Docker networking setup swallows the request for ~11 seconds before routing out to the internet, but only for some URLs.

Where can I look to debug this further?

### Update 1 - nslookup

Upon running an `nslookup` on the host, I see that two DNS queries seem to fail (and this is where the 11 seconds is spent):

```
$ nslookup <my api>.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
Server:         192.168.65.7
Address:        192.168.65.7#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   <my api>.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
Address: 18.169.197.242
Name:   <my api>.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
Address: 18.168.60.90
Name:   <my api>.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
Address: 18.134.119.33
;; communications error to 192.168.65.7#53: timed out
;; communications error to 192.168.65.7#53: timed out
```

I therefore assume that this `192.168.65.7` is where a DNS server is meant to be on my virtual network. *Something* is there...

```
$ ping 192.168.65.7
PING 192.168.65.7 (192.168.65.7) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.65.7: icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=0.043 ms
```

Comment: I have replicated this in a regular `ubuntu` container, outside of the VSCode ecosystem. Same 11 second delay!

Comment: I have tested the `ubuntu` container on the default `bridge` network and on a `host` network, still seeing the slow DNS lookup on `192.168.65.7`.